# svn command line equivalent of 'git log -p'?

Tags: git, svn, command-line, logging

Is there an equivalent of `git log -p` using the svn command line tool? `svn log -v` shows file names but not changes.

I would like to see the patches introduced by prior commits. If not possible, is there a way to get the patch (not compared to head, just the changeset) introduced by a single previous commit?

Comment: Use `git svn` as your Subversion client?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it makes a patch file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`svn log --diff` is the equivalent of `git log -p`.

For a single revision you can use `svn diff -c <revision>` which in git would be `git show <revision>`.

Comment: FYI this is only in version 1.7, and when writing this question the latest version out was 1.6. For 1.7 this is the right answer. Fortunately I don't have to deal with svn anymore.

Comment: True, `svn log --diff` is new with 1.7. `svn diff -c` worked with 1.6

Comment: and equivalent of HEAD or HEAD^2 etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

There's not an exact match; because, git deals with files while svn deals with filesystems.  However, there are close matches.

`svn diff` does most of what `git log -p` does.  [Someone else has already written up a nice tutorial on how to make and apply patches using svn commands](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/).  I think you might find it useful.

Note that while the tutorial makes a patch file of local changes against the last checked out version, you can also use the `-r 4:7` options to construct a patch of all changes between revisions 4 and 7.  Some combination of `svn log` to identify the specific revisions and `svn diff` probably will give you exactly what you want.